# php regex mach before and after specific word

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with data that looks like this:

```
$string = '
    foo=bar
    badge_name_foo=foo
    bar_badge_name=bar
    bar=baz
';
```

I want to match all `*_badge_name` and `badge_name_*` strings.

The regex im using is this:
`preg_match_all('~(?:(\w+)_)?badge_name(?:_(\w+))?~', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);`

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => badge_name_foo
            [1] => 
            [2] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar_badge_name
            [1] => bar
        )

)
```

The `*_badge_name` is working fine, but on `badge_name_*` there is every time a empty value? Now how can i remove that with `preg_match_all`

Expected result should be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => badge_name_foo
            [1] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar_badge_name
            [1] => bar
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use [**BRANCH RESET** feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

> [Alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside a branch reset group share the same capturing groups. The syntax is `(?|regex)` where `(?|` opens the group and `regex` is any regular expression. If you don't use any alternation or capturing groups inside the branch reset group, then its special function doesn't come into play. It then acts as a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncapture).

Use

```
(?|(\w+)_badge_name|badge_name_(\w+))
^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YGLDKl/1).

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Avi9J2):

```
$re = '/(?|(\w+)_badge_name|badge_name_(\w+))/';
$str = 'foo=bar
badge_name_foo=foo
bar_badge_name=bar
bar=baz';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => badge_name_foo
            [1] => bar_badge_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )

)
```